# duplicate Incoming Emails

Tags: exchange-migration, ibm-domino, email

i'm planing the migration of my corporative messaging platform, from lotus domino to ms exchange. i have almost no experience with lotus domino, but a lot of experience designinng and supporting ms exchange. to make short a long story, migrating users mails calendars and so, easy.. almost done. but one of the requirements for this project, is have both servers (domino & exchange) synchronized with same mails. due to my lack of experience with lotus, i cant even imagine how to do this. so here's my idea that i would like if you could helpme to realize if this is possible: 
 - im thinking in use a software or aplication (doesnt matter if paid, free, open-source) that could deliver all incoming mails from internet to both server. i know this will have to be implemented in my DMZ MX server, so no problem with this. and i cand imagine this application should deliver incoming mails to one mailserver and then copy the same mail to the other server.

so this is possible or is so much dreaming? (i'been 20 hours working and planning this project, i really dont want to mess with lotus domino).

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to share the same SMTP address space between Lotus and Exchange... with the caveat that each system has the same email addresses for each user. Microsoft details how to share an SMTP address space between two servers [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321721) and it sounds to me like you're going to have to go with method 2.

Comment: Thanks A lot for refresh my memory!! you're A genious. now i remember i've done this procedure few years ago, when i was exchange consultant (good times) and do it on a client who was migrating from linux exim to exchange 2007. again, thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: Glad to help...